# EaselJS: Why does caching make my rendering slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, easeljs

I'm trying to improve performance on our canvas as everything (multiple areas) is being redrawn on every `stage.update()`, which is how it works. I'd like to draw / add only a single area. I can get this to work, but then all previous areas are removed because of the `update`. I found caching might be a performance improvement, but it actually slows rendering down.

Example code:

```
self.areaMask = new createjs.Shape();
self.areaMask.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
self.areaMask.cache(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

The weird part is that the moment I enable this caching, it actually makes the rendering slower. Only when I decrease the optional fourth `scale` parameter to `0.1` the performance is, slightly, better.

I'd like to understand how this is possible, what could I be doing wrong?

Is there another better way to get the desired behaviour? (only draw / add specified areas, don't redraw all areas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching will improve things in most browsers, provided:

1. The browser can put the content on the GPU. If it can not, then the CPU is used to draw the images, which can be slower. Most browsers will work fine in most cases, but sometimes you see the opposite effect. For example, the [EaselJS cache demo](http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/Cache.html) sometimes performs worse in Safari, despite working better everywhere else. What browsers/devices are you testing on?
2. The caching is done right. If you cache a ton of small things separately, then you are creating a lot of small images in the background. A better approach is to use something like SpriteSheetBuilder in these cases, as a reduction in the number of textures you have improves the chances that the GPU will play nice.
3. Your caching is done once, not a lot. If you cache something every frame (like in a tick), then the caching will not be effective. This is because it has to draw the vector/group content each frame into an off-screen canvas, and then draw that canvas to the main stage. This is more work than just drawing the vectors.

There is currently no support in EaselJS to draw specific areas of the stage. There are techniques like updating an off-screen cache, and drawing that once to the stage - but that is it.

I would be curious to see your code in action, and might be able to tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you for the information, very useful. I found some issues where caching of small objects was done too many times. I'll have to further look into more efficient use of the cache. Is there a way to determine wether CPU or GPU is used for caching?

Comment: That is good news :) There isn't really a way to tell as far as I know, though the browser might have tools to indicate it that I am unaware of. Pretty much if you start seeing performance issues like that, the CPU is likely involved or taking over. Note that some things can not be hardware accelerated, such as Graphics, Dropshadows, Text, etc. Caching should help with most of those things when used properly.